# TCP communcation - HyperV virtual machine opening port on host

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, firewall, tcp

Here's the summary of my fight to connect to a port on the hypervisor host from a VM hosted on the same machine:

- Set up in the Hyper-V Manager:

  - Virtual Switch Settings
  - Internal
  - 'Enable virtual LAN identification for management operating system'
  - VLAN number 2
- Set up the Virtual Machine (client-01)

  - Network Adapter Settings
  - 'Enable virtual LAN identification'
  - VLAN number 2
- Configured IP4 on adapter of host desktop01 (host):
  192.168.5.1
  255.255.255.0
- Configured IP4 on adapter of host client-01 (vm):
  192.168.5.10
  255.255.255.0
- The client can successfully navigate to 'http://desktop01' port 80 running on the host (there's a small website running on the host)
- Ping 192.168.5.1 from client is OK
- Ping 192.168.5.10 from host is OK
- Added 10000 as OK for incoming in Windows Firewall on host
- Opened a listener on 10000 on the host, but on the client:

```
PS C:\Users\user-01> test-netconnection -ComputerName 192.168.5.1 -Port 10000
WARNING: TCP connect to 192.168.5.1:10000 failed

ComputerName           : 192.168.5.1
RemoteAddress          : 192.168.5.1
RemotePort             : 10000
InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet
SourceAddress          : 192.168.5.10
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
```

The listener is a C# programme I wrote. You may suspect an issue with it, but PowerShell has no problem establishing a connection to it from the same machine. So.. it smells like a firewall thing, but I already made an entry there and there's nothing in the log file. What gives?

Comment: I turned the firewall off completely and the issue persists. So weird.

Answer (score 0):

I dropped back to the 'Default Switch' instead of 'VLAN Number 2' and now everything is working perfectly. So - the lesson is to use the default switch.

Comment: The Hyper-V switches behave very unpredictable, I also almost always use the Default one, only when I want the whole traffic to go through a virtualised router I use a nonstandard switch. But as far as I know there is no real disadvantage of using the default one, it just works...

Comment: Thanks mate for your ideas. I added it originally because I thought it had to be on 'LAN ID management'. Great way to waste 2 hours :P